# Do i need grpc-web library even if the browser supports http2?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-web

I'm a newbie developer. I wanna know, Do i need grpc-web library even if the browser supports HTTP2 ?. If the answer is yes, please tell me why

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to [this grpc.io blog post](https://grpc.io/blog/state-of-grpc-web/), as of 2019 browsers did not support fine-grained control of HTTP2 requests needed to implement direct gRPC connection from javascript.

For this reason a separate library and proxy, such as implemented by gRPC-Web, is needed.